# WPF 3D graphics redraw when data changes

Tags: wpf

I am rendering a 3D contour surface from data.  I get new data every few seconds from real time monitoring and need to redraw using the new data. All of the examples I can find only show how render the 3D contour surface from fixed data.

I can't find an example of explanation of how to (clear, delete, erase) the mesh or model and redraw with new data.

Can anyone point me to an example or explain how to redraw the 3D contour surface with the new data.

Comment: If you know how to calculate your mesh, just use MVVM and bind your data to the `MeshGeometry3D`. [Take a look](https://imgur.com/uo6G4xY).

Answer (score -1):

I have solved this issue with the help of several answered questions.

1. Removed all children of the Model3DGroup 'main_model_3D_group'.

   for (int i = main_model_3D_group.Children.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
   {
       if (main_model_3D_group.Children[i] is GeometryModel3D)
       main_model_3D_group.Children.RemoveAt(i);
   }
2. rebuild the GeometryModel3D objects
3. add the GeometryModel3D objects back to the children of the main_model_3D_group.

Second Issue encountered:
I used an ImageBrush to get a gradient colored surface material.
The ImageBrush.ImageSource locks the file so you can't save the same filename with new color data.
Solved this with the following function;

```
public ImageSource BitmapFromUri(Uri source)
{
    bitmap.BeginInit();
    bitmap.UriSource = source;
    bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmap.EndInit();
    return bitmap;
```

}

This function leaves Uri source (xxx.PNG file) unlocked, but the 2nd call doesn't reload the file (assume because it is cached).  Solved this by using 2 filename (odd/even). So every other call used a different filename.